# jQuery - header flashes on and off

Tags: jquery, css, header

Hello guys here is my jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > 100 && scroll < 300){
                $('#header').fadeOut();
            }

            if (scroll > 300){
                $('#header').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The #header is hidden by default, and I want it to unhide further down the page, but if I change any of the numbers in that jQuery the header will just flash on and off. I don't understand the code well enough to understand why that's happening.

Comment: what will happen if you rewrite condition as (  (scroll > 100) && (scroll < 300) )  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on and off effect (blinking efffect) is mainly due to 1 pixel that your fade effect is missing. **So just use :** 
`scroll >= 300` **instead of :** `scroll > 300`

Answer (score 0):

i agree with @Adam Barker,also you can stop the animate queue:$('#header').stop(true).fadeIn();